# Python polling file descriptor not returning the last line

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, subprocess, file-descriptor

I want to be able to read and follow the logs from a journalctl command for purposes of log monitoring. There is this strange behaviour where it doesn't show the last line of the log.
I don't understand what is happening and would really appreciate some insights into how to fix this.

Here is my current code:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import select
 
args = ['journalctl', '-u', 'foo.service', '--follow']
f = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = select.poll()
p.register(f.stdout)

while True:
    if p.poll(1):
        line = f.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            print(line.strip())
```

Note that if I do a `f.stdout.readline()` again it does spit out the last line.

Appreciate your help kind folks!

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with polling the file but I have found that not using it doesn't cause any problems either.

This seems to get the job done just as well.

```
import sys
import subprocess
 
args = ['journalctl', '-u', 'foo.service', '--follow']
f = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = f.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print(line.strip().decode('utf-8'))
```